# Delay loop calling animation process

Tags: swift, xcode, delay

Here is a section of my code where I am trying to delay a function called `dropText` that drops a name from the top of the screen. I tried using a delay function but it delays then drops them all at once. What am I missing, or is this method just plain wrong? Thanks in advance:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(
        deadline: DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC), execute: closure)
}

//New group choose method
func groupChoose()
{
    //loop through the players
    for x in 0...players - 1{
            //drop the name in from the top of the screen
            delay(2.0) {
            self.dropText(playing[x])
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to with `Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)` ?

Comment: Unterlated but you can replace cumbersome `Double(Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)` with `.seconds(Int(delay))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because you are delaying all of them at once! You should try to assign different delay time to each one:

```
for x in 1...players {
   //drop the name in from the top of the screen
   delay(2.0 * x) {
   self.dropText(playing[x-1])
}
```

---

#### Refactored

Try to not call array elements by index:

```
for playing in playing.enumerated() {
// drop the name in from the top of the screen
let player = playing.offset + 1
delay(2.0 * player) {
    self.dropText(playing.element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the loop. You are calling `asyncAfter` almost immediately one after another. So the text is dropped after the delay *almost immediately one after another*, too.

I recommend to use a `Timer`

```
func delay(_ delay: Double, numberOfIterations: Int, closure:@escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    var counter = 0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true) { timer in
        DispatchQueue.main.async { closure(counter-1) }
        counter += 1
        if counter == numberOfIterations { timer.invalidate() }
    }
}
```

and

```
func groupChoose()
{
    delay(2.0, numberOfIterations: players) { counter in
         self.dropText(playing[counter])
    }
}
```